# Let X be a set with 30 elements. How many equivalence relations can be defined on X if every class of the relation must have exactly 6 elements?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am not really sure about my approach. I'm thinking of the ways to partition the set X into 5 classes with 6 elements each.

I am thinking of the "word" $a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5a_6|a_7\dots a_{30}$ that has $30$  $a_i$ elements and 4 bars. I am thinking of the permutations of this word with fixed bars, and dividing the total of permutations by 6! repeated cases I'd get since every partition is appearing 6! times. But permutating with fixed bars is the same as them not being there at all, so the answer is the total number of permutations divided by 6!

$Var(30,24) = \frac{30!}{6!}$

Is this correct? Is there another way to think this problem?

Comment: Hint. How many ways are there to choose six elements for the first class? Then six more, and so on. Finally, it doesn't matter what order you choose the classes in.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{5!} \binom{30}{6,6,6,6,6} 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Part of what makes your answer in your post incorrect is that withing an equivalence class, the order that the elements of the class are written in does not matter.  If the first class included $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_6\}$ this is the same as though the first class had $\{a_6,a_5,a_4,\dots,a_1\}$

Comment: Never seen that notation Donald. What Ethan said was my first approach but I was afraid it'd be wrong

Comment: @Jmoravitz that's why I divide by 6!, because each order appears 6! times. Or should I be dividing by 6!^5?

Comment: Ohhh I should be dividing by $6!^5$ if I do a cascade like Ethan and Donald said?

Comment: The notation Donald uses is a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients).  Much like how binomial coefficients are used, a multinomial coefficient $\binom{n}{a,b,\dots k}$ is the number of strings of length $n$ with $a$ `A`'s, $b$ `B`'s, ..., on up to $k$ `K`'s.  One has $\binom{n}{a,b,\dots,k}=\frac{n!}{a!b!\cdots k!}$

Comment: In this case $\frac{1}{5!}\binom{30}{6,6,6,6,6}=\frac{1}{5!}\cdot\frac{30!}{6!6!6!6!6!}$

Comment: Ok so I got the cascade for $6!^5$. Where does the $\frac{1}{5!}$ come from?

Comment: I know it is from repeated cases but not how those cases repeat. COunting 5! times the same partitions?

Comment: The additional division by $5!$ is because we don't care which was "the first equivalence class" and which was "the second equivalence class" etc... we only care about which elements are together in their respective equivalence classes, wherever they happen to be listed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $30\choose 6$ ways to pick the first class, then $24\choose 6$ to choose the second class, then $18\choose 6$, $12\choose 6$, and $6\choose 6$. However, this overcounts by a factor of $5!$ because the order of picking the equivalence classes does not matter. So we end up with
$$ \frac{30!}{6!24!}\cdot \frac{24!}{6!18!}\cdot\frac{18!}{6!12!}\cdot\frac{12!}{6!6!}\cdot\frac{6!}{6!0!}\cdot\frac1{5!}=\frac{30!}{6!^55!}$$

---

Or: There are $29\choose 5$ ways to extend the smallest element to an equivalence class. After that, there are $23\choose 5$ ways to extend the then smallest unused element to an equivalence class, then $17\choose 5$, $11\choose 5$, and $5\choose 5$. Now we get
$$ \frac{29!}{5!24!}\cdot \frac{23!}{5!18!}\cdot \frac{17!}{5!12!}\cdot \frac{11!}{5!6!}\cdot \frac{5!}{5!0!}.$$
Can you see wha that's the same?

Comment: Kinda. What do you mean by smallest?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio Any finite set can be ordered.  For example, a set of students in a classroom can be ordered by their height, or by their age, or by their last name, etc...  Without loss of generality, we can say that our 30 element set is simply the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,30\}$.  The smallest element here corresponding to our usual meaning of smallest, in this case the element $1$.  Once $1$ and those elements selected to be chosen in it's equivalence class are removed from the available pool, there will be a new smallest.  Maybe its $2$, maybe its $5$, etc... depending on what was picked.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that way. It's also foolproof for counting more than once if you forget to divide repeated cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I always like to visually think about it as follows:

Line up all $30$ elements. Clearly there are $30!$ to do this.

Now create the $5$ groups by putting the first $6$ elements of the line-up in a group, the second $6$ in another, etc.

In other words, each of the $30!$ possible line-ups translates into a partition.

However, this overcounts the number of possible partitions in two ways:

First, we can shuffle around the first $6$ elements in the line-up, and still end up with the same partition. Of course, the same goes for the second $6$ elements, etc. So, we need to divide by $6!^5$

Second, we can swap any of the groups of $6$ elements forming a group with any other $6$ elements forming a group. That is, the are $5!$ ways in which these groups will be ordered in the loin-up, each resulting in the same partition. So, we also need to divide by $5!$

Total:

$$\frac{30!}{(6!)^5 \cdot 5!}$$

Comment: Yeah I thought of it like this by didn't take into account swapping groups and divided by 6! Only once